# Documents required for re-entering Schengen area on multiple entry visa

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, multiple-entry

I already got Schengen Visa with Multiple Entries since last year.
I think I was lucky because I applied for Single Entry but Embassy gave me Multiple Entry for one year.

So I would like to ask what documents should I prepare for the 2nd time entry to Europe.
Is it the same documents (Insurance, Ticket, Bank Statement) during I apply for visa?

In case immigration would check.

Comment: is your visa valid until the end of your trip?

Comment: Dear, Dirty flow.. yes my visa will cover until end of my trip

Answer (score 5):

You will need your passport, ticket and insurance. Bank statement is only needed when applying for visa but not when travelling. Out of personal experience in EU they do not check anything usually other than your passport and visa.

Comment: Yes they don't check anything at all I travelled with my multiple-entry visa all the time and all they asked was that what am I doing here?

Answer (score 3):

Usually they dont check anything except your passport and visa.
but better to carry 
1.Invitation letter (Incase of a business visa)
2.Travel Insurance (Mandatory document, should cover the travel duration)
3.Accomodation proof (Hotel bookings)
4.Air Tickets (to and fro)